# How to read values of an array outside valueChanges after populating it inside a valueChanges subscription angularfire

Tags: javascript, typescript, angularfire2, angularfire, angularfire5

it's been three days and i'm still looking for a solution to this.

Basically i have a class attribute variable `dataMapped` which is going to be an array of course

i populate it inside `getAllPersonnel()` function

```
getAllPersonnel(){
    this.personnelService.getAllPersonnel().valueChanges().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataMapped = data ;
      })
  }
```

now i want to use the array variable `this.dataMapped` outside the `getAllPersonnel()` function.

i tried this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllPersonnel();
    console.log(this.dataMapped); <== returns null
  }
```

but i get 
[Undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxxkT.jpg)

the purpose of all of this is that i want to populate an angular material `mat-table` and i need to initialise the data source inside the constructor not inside the getAllPersonnel() function.

so instead of this :

```
getAllPersonnel(){
    this.personnelService.getAllPersonnel().valueChanges().subscribe(
      data => {
        data.forEach(personnel => {
          let personnelData :PersonnelData ; 
          personnelData = {
            image:personnel.image , 
            nom: personnel.nom,
            prenom: personnel.prenom,
            secteur: personnel.secteur,
            note: personnel.note,
            promotion: personnel.promotion
          }
          this.personnelDataArray.push(personnelData)
        })
        this.dataSource = new  MatTableDataSource<PersonnelData>(this.personnelDataArray);  <== i dont want the initialisation here
      }
    )
  }
```

i want the function to directly retrun an array filled with the subscription data so i can use it inside my constructor, something like this :

```
constructor(private personnelService : PersonnelService) { 
    this.getAllPersonnel();
    this.dataSource = new  MatTableDataSource<PersonnelData>(this.getAllPersonnel());
  }
```

i'd be appreciative to any kind of help guys thank you .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)